# Add emacs #...# to helm boring files

Tags: helm

I want to add the emacs `#...#` files to the boring file list. I don't know how the helm regexp engine works since dots are not escaped, I have tried to manually escape them with a backslash but it doesn't work.

The standard regexp for my need would be `#.+#` with the sequence `.+` interpreted as "any character at least one time".

If someone would like to briefly explain how the helm regexp engine works I'll be really happy!

Comment: Have you changed `helm-ff-skip-boring-files`? It's nil by default.  `#.+#` works for me when it's non-nil.

Comment: Yes it's change.
Ok, the problem came from that in fact I have entered the string regexp `"\\^#.+#$"` and the anchor was not interpreted as the beginning of the string. All right, now I understand my error, the two backslashes used do describe extensions are buffers beginning with a `*` are here to escape the dot or the star... Everythings fine ! Sorry for the disturbance :/